# pyqtgraph custom tick labels potential bug

Tags: qt, python-3.x, pyqtgraph

I'm using PyQtGraph and embedding a graph into a Qt program.  I've added `axisItems` to the `PlotWidget`'s constructor.  It seems to do something a bit weird; I get some off line with 0___1 in the top right-hand corner.  Does anyone know what is causing this and/or how to get rid of it?

I've attached a picture showing this and my code to generate what's in the picture.

If I don't add the AxisItem to the constructor (hence not getting my custom tick labels), the issue doesn't occur.

[image: qtwindow]

```
import sys
import numpy as np
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui, QtUiTools, QtXml
from ui import *
import pyqtgraph as pg


class PlotWidgetBarGraph(pg.PlotWidget):
    def __init__(self, **opts):
        # Add custom tick strings.
        xDict = {1.:'1', 2.:'2', 3.:'3', 4.:'4',
                 5.:'5', 6.:'6', 7.:'7', 8.:'8',
                 9.:'1/2', 10.:'1/3', 11.:'1/4',
                 12.:'2/3', 13.:'2/4', 14.:'3/4',
                 15.:'1/2/3', 16.:'2/3/4',
                 17:'1/2/3/4'}
        xAxis = pg.AxisItem(orientation='bottom')
        xAxis.setTicks([xDict.items(), []])

        super().__init__(axisItems={'bottom': xAxis})

        # Create and add bar graph.
        bg = pg.BarGraphItem(**opts)
        self.addItem(bg)    

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setupUi(self)

        splitter = QtGui.QSplitter(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        x = np.arange(20)
        y = np.abs(np.sin(x))+0.1
        plot1 = PlotWidgetBarGraph(x=x, height=y, width=0.8, brush='b')
        plot2 = PlotWidgetBarGraph(x=x, height=y, width=0.8, brush='b')
        splitter.addWidget(plot1)
        splitter.addWidget(plot2)
        splitter.setStretchFactor(0, 1)
        splitter.setStretchFactor(1, 2)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(splitter)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: This is a known and fixed bug. Try updating pyqtgraph. See: https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/pull/136 and https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/commit/9df4df55c49ace05020e6b7c52128fdce09e2a8d

Comment: Excellent!  Thanks for that!  The package I was using in Arch had an older version.